# Date format: How to set date in new/editForm via Javascript in SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, date, format

I'll try to set a date field within a SharePoint 2016 new-, or edit form via jQuery.

Works fine so far:

```
fieldJqueryObject.find('input[type="text"]').val('08/28/2019')
```

The problem: It works only if I send the string according to the format set up in the site settings (here: MM/DD/YYYY). If, for instance, I use the German format in regional settings (DD.MM.YYYY) it won't work if I write the english value in the field.

Of course, reading the value also is a problem. Can I retrieve the date/time format via REST API or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a half solution but you can try it. If you enter dd/MM/YYYY, it should work.

You can get the regional settings using REST API as shown below.

```
https://spdev.sharepoint.com/sites/SPTeam/_api/web/RegionalSettings/
```

You can get the date format number and date separatore using the above api

or

```
https://spdev.sharepoint.com/sites/SPTeam/_api/web/RegionalSettings/TimeZone
```